# Multiple names in CSS, including elements in declaration: syntax questions

Tags: html, css, syntax

I came across these on the new job I just started. I don't have web experience so my knowledge is pretty basic. I'm not sure what the below do. I've never come across or used syntax like this before. I was able to find that the `#TAFeedback` will apply to any element with that id, but that's all I could dig up.

```css
.howmanyinstate .ctrlHolder ol 
{
    width:90%;
    float:right;
}

#TAFeedBack div.ctrlHolder table
{
    background:none !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.howmanyinstate .ctrlHolder ol
```

applies the style to all ordered lists `ol` in an element that has a class `ctrlHolder` and that element is a child of an element with class `howmanyinstate`

For example:

```
<div class="howmanyinstate">
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
        <ol>
           ...
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A CSS rule identifies the element to which it applies by using a selector.

Here is a writeup on [CSS Selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref)

The following is a descendant selector: `#TAFeedBack div.ctrlHolder table` indicates that it applies to a `table` that is contained in a `div` that has the attribute `class="ctrlHolder"` which is contained inside an element that has `id="TAFeedBack"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
.howmanyinstate .ctrlHolder ol
```

applies to any `ol` element within any element with a class of `ctrlHolder` which is in itself inside any element with a class of `howmanyinstate`

I'm not sure if you already know this, but this is known as a "css selector". Perhaps something you might want to read up on.